# How to Combine an Ionic App with native iOS app and behave like one app?

Tags: ios, swift, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an ionic 3 app currently listed on the app store. I have created a native `caller app` using Swift and agora SDK, where I will have a video streaming using RTC. In the caller app, I need the `channelID` to initialize the streaming.

I have the functionality to get the call in the first app. My only job to while accepting the call in the first app I need to open the second app and pass the `channelID`. In the second app, I need to fetch the `channelID` and proceed with the streaming.

I can just make the second app a different app, open from the first app using Deepkinking. But in this case, the user needs to download two separate apps.

But I have heard the term `Combined apps in iOS`. Where the user needs to download the only main app and the second caller app will work as a shadow app. The caller app will not be visible in the app list in the device or not needed to download separately.

Please suggest me any solution for this,

1. how to combine these two apps?
2. How to parse the `channelID` from the first app to the caller app and how to catch the `channelID` in the caller app?

   ```
   // caller app ViewController

   class ViewController: UIViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
      let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
      "VideoChatViewController") as? VideoChatViewController
       viewController?.channelID = "hello-video"

      // I want to make this channelID to be dynamic which will come from the first app.

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
   }
   ```

> I have to make the caller app a native app as iOS 13 has stopped different APIs for webrtc. And ionic is reliable on web views. But I can not make the whole app in native now. So I have decided to make the caller part only in native and combine two related apps to One app.

Comment: SImple Man doesn't use Agora SDK in Ionic. Be clear what you want an APP in ionic or APP using swift. Don't mix the two.

Comment: ok, sir. Thank you. I hope the suggestion would work for me.

Comment: How about if you want to mix the two. I think that's what he is asking. Which is something I am looking to do as well. In this world, there is never this or that... is take this and that some of the other. @sibabratswain have you find anything regarding this?